# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 2-7: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python-3.x, unicode

I would like to rename all the files in a certain directory. The old filename with a relative path is 'full_fname', after detoxing the filenames is 'full_new_fname' as in the picture. I am working in a Linux environment with Python 3.6 and using Jupyter notebook.

[image]

I use the following command to rename;

```
os.rename(full_fname,full_new_fname)
```

I get the error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 2-7: ordinal not in range(128)

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and see if it works:

```
os.rename(full_fname.encode('U8'), full_new_fname.encode('U8'))
```

Comment: Unicode names should work.  The real problem is likely the Linux environment is not correctly indicating the terminal is UTF-8.  See https://perlgeek.de/en/article/set-up-a-clean-utf8-environment